# Is it possible to load more pages with javascript inside using infinity-scroll?

Tags: php, javascript, html, scroll

my question is the following ,i have a dynamic page that fetches images from the database for my products. I display 14 products with sub-product images over here : "http://www.14u-fashion.com/shop/cat/65". I want to remove the arrows and made it an infinity scroll , i used this library : "github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll" , everything works fine (working here "dokimastiko.14u-fashion.com/shop/cat/65") but when i load more content on scroll the javascript that makes the images turn (and the arrows on each product 'clickable') doesn't carry on. My code so far is this

```
$o . ="$('#catview').infinitescroll({
                   navSelector:'div.nextPage',             
                   nextSelector:'div.nextPage a:first',
                   itemSelector:'#catview div.loadPage',
                   loading: 
                   {
                    finishedMsg: '',
                    msgText: '',
                    img : '/../../../images/loading.gif',
                    },
                    debug:true;
                   animate: true,

   });
   ";
```

Any way to make it work with javascript? I tried with pathParse but even more errors occur

Comment: make your js code that makes images turn into a function and use the callback `$(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback])` to call the function again

Comment: On a side note, your image url `img : '/../../../images/loading.gif'` seems wrong. You are starting at the root directory and then going several directories up.

Comment: no that's corrects image displays correctly and i am actually starting 3 directories inside the directory root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your js code that makes images turn into a function and use the optional callback `$(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback])` to call the function again

Something like this:

```
function codeForImageTurn(){
    //turn image, click stuff
}

//run once when page load
codeForImageTurn();


//add as callback everytime scroll elements are added so it will re-run
$o. = "$('#catview').infinitescroll({
    navSelector:'div.nextPage',             
    nextSelector:'div.nextPage a:first',
    itemSelector:'#catview div.loadPage',
    loading: 
    {
        finishedMsg: '',
        msgText: '',
        img : '/../../../images/loading.gif', //starting with `/` means root, you can't go anything up
    },
    debug:true;
    animate: true,

},function(){
    codeForImageTurn();
});
";
```

Comment: it doesn't want to run :( my code so far is full of $o.=""; should i remove them all? does the possition matters?

Comment: @user1919915 Your website `dokimastiko.14u-fashion.com/shop/cat/65` does not open for me so I can't see your full code to say the correct placement. and talking about that, why you using the jQuery inside a variable?

Comment: it should work now, the $o.= variable is beeing passed to html , the backend is codeigniter, i can't make it work though , i think its because i have a jQuery (or caroufredsel) inside the function ? atm the function is $o .= "function codeForImageTurn(){";
                    $o .= "$('.p" . $pid . "').caroufredsel({";

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JVmpYQgF
After line 150 is the code i try to run , it doesn't work...

Comment: For some reason now your website opened. Saying `codeForImageTurn is not defined`.. Looking at the php and the html, there is a serious problem: The JS can't be inside the product loop! It has to be declared only ONCE. (p.s: the jquery ready is wrong: `<script>$(function codeForImageTurn(){` -> `<script>$(function(){  codeForImageTurn(){`. And dont forget to add the `});` at the end.).. My tip is: Remove all javascript codes from `$o`. Put all of them ONCE just before `return $o`

Comment: i moved all script at the end but nothing works now, script related... that's the result http://pastebin.com/dKEJzZni

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FxYA9EaU - Lots of problems in the JS writing. Fixed and put the comments for each error. TIP: the best way to code is to make a dummy HTML, do the JavaScript in the dummy and only after you make sure the code is okay, you add the server-side code, because this way you are sure the thing works.

Comment: still can't figure it out... chrome says unexpected ; and firefox says missing )...(before the last }); ) if i add it i see no javascript problems but the codeForImageTurn function doesn't work

Comment: Let's do like I said. Remove the JS code from the PHP for a while. Render the page as HTML and save it using the browser as a common .html file (with files). Then grab it and before the `</body>` add the code and let's see if it runs.